# ID getter returns null in Hibernate proxy when the entity implements an interface

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate and I have a problem that when I load an entity using `Session.load`, the ID getter returns `null`.

My entities all inherit from the following interface:

```
public interface Entity {
    Object getId();
}
```

An example of an entity that implements this interface:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "`Dog`")
public class Dog implements Entity {
    private java.util.UUID id;

    @javax.persistence.Id
    @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "`Id`", nullable = false)
    @Override
    public java.util.UUID getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    //...
```

The `getId` getter in the entity implements the `getId` of the interface, but changes the return type.

When I load this entity using `Session.load`, `getId` returns `null` when I call `Dog.getId`, but not when I call `Entity.getId`.

```
Dog dog = (Dog)session.load(Dog.class, id);

assert dog.getId() != null; // This fails
assert ((Entity)dog).getId() != null; // This succeeds
```

When I trace execution of `dog.getId()`, it isn't handled by the proxy but goes into the actual implementation. It thus gets the value of the `id` field on `Dog`, which is `null` because it's a proxy.

Why is this?

Comment: The problem has disappeared and I was not able to find out what the real problem was. I tried changing the return type of `Entity.getId` to `UUID`, which threw an `AbstractMethodError`. In the end, upgrading to the latest Hibernate version, recompiling a bunch of times and clearing the `.m2` Maven cache made the problem go away.